# How to avoid triggering useEffect on every render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a custom hook that accepts an object and in turn calls `useEffect`. The object can contain inline functions.

```js
const stuff = useValidation({
  fields: {
    username: { /* more nested objects */ }
  },
  onSubmit: () => alert('submitted'),
});
```

The hook implementation looks like this:

```js
function useValidation(config) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(validationReducer);
  useEffect(() => {
    validateFields(config.fields, state);
  }, [config.fields, state]);
}
```

There's more to it ([here's the actual implementation](https://codesandbox.io/s/3q67o5oyz6)), but these are the relevant parts.

When I create the object inline, the `useEffect` runs continuously. This happens because React uses reference equality (not deep equality) to check whether or not stuff has changed.

I can "fix" this by either wrapping my config in `useMemo`, or move it outside of the render method. Both of these are pretty bad for developer experience.

I tried Kent C. Dodds' [`use-deep-compare-effect`](https://github.com/kentcdodds/use-deep-compare-effect) library, but since I'm allowing inline arrow functions in my config, it doesn't "work".

Preferably, I'd love to be able to let the user input an inline object, and let me deal with any changes somehow.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that `useEffect` is called every render because the config you pass to `useValidation` is created on the fly every time. My suggestion would be to put this in a state somewhere either in your component where you use `useValidation` or within the `useValidation` itself like so:

```
function useValidation(config) {
  const [storedConfig, setStoredConfig] = useState(config);
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(validationReducer);

  useEffect(() => {
    validateFields(config.fields, state);
  }, [storedConfig.fields, state]);
}
```

If the config is changeable then you should have it stored outside of the hook, either way make sure the config isn't a new object every render.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I agree, my question was more about what i can do to skip saving the config outside the hook. «Outiside» the hook means it’s left to the consumer of my hook - which I’m trying to simplify the developer experience for.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you should not put objects or arrays on the array, but the individual attributes inside it, like this:

```
function useValidation(config) {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(validationReducer);
  useEffect(() => {
    validateFields(config.fields, state);
  }, [config.fields.username, state]);
}
```

I don't know what your `state` is, but should be an immutable value such as a string, number, boolean, etc.

Same thing with `Date` objects, they should be casted to `String` first.

Answer (score -1):

looks like it's only Syntax Error in your code.

your function should look like this

```
function useValidation(config) {
 const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(validationReducer);
  useEffect(() => {
    validateFields(config.fields, state);
  }, [config.fields, state])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - fixed my example code. Unfortunately, the issue persists.